# Laravel Left join not returing all records with where clause

Tags: laravel

I am not getting all records in left join.
my core query is like `SELECT cities.*, states.name as state FROM cities LEFT JOIN states ON cities.states_id = states.id` its working well

my laravel query is like this

```
      $all_city = DB::table('cities')
            ->leftjoin('states', 'cities.states_id', '=', 'states.id') 
            ->where([['states.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$state.'%'], ['cities.name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%']])
            ->select('cities.*', 'states.name as state')
            ->orderBy($sort_field, $sort_type)
            ->paginate($pagination);
            return response()->json($all_city);
```

Laravel returning only those records which are unique in both. And if i remove where clause from this then its working well. 
Can someone suggest whats going wrong.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem not in in join clause, but in where clause ...

the where clause take three parameters first for column second for operator and the third for the value you want to compare ...

you should divide this where:

```
->where([['states.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$state.'%'], ['cities.name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%']])
```

to:

```
->where('states.name','like','{$state}%')->where('cities.name','Like','%{$name}%');
```

this article explains using like in where:

https://freek.dev/1182-searching-models-using-a-where-like-query-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this:

```
$all_city = DB::table('cities')
                ->leftJoin('states', 'cities.states_id', '=', 'states.id') 
                ->where('states.name', 'like', '%'.$state.'%')
                ->where('cities.name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
                ->select('cities.*', 'states.name as state')
                ->orderBy($sort_field, $sort_type)
                ->paginate($pagination);
       return response()->json($all_city);
```